# Is there an OpenCV equivalent of scipy.ndimage.find_objects?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, scipy

I am trying to get an array of bounding boxes from a large image of labeled connected components, using scipy this is straight forward, but I am struggling to figure out how to do it using OpenCV

using scipy:

```
mask = misc.imread(mask_file) 
labels = scipy.ndimage.label(mask)[0] 
regions = scipy.ndimage.find_objects(labels)
```

using opencv:

```
mask = cv2.imread(mask_file,2)
no_components, components = cv2.connectedComponents(mask)
regions = ???
```

I cannot find a function for extracting an array of bounding boxes

Any ideas much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at cv2.findContours - could fit your need